# Append from input field to multiple select

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following code that appends value from one multiple field to another and remove value from one multiple field with javascript.

```
<html>  
<head>      
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

 <script type="text/javascript">  
  $().ready(function() {  

   $('#add').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
   });  

   $('#remove').click(function() {  
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove();  
   });  

  });  
 </script>  

</head>  

<body>  

  <select multiple id="select1">  
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>  
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>  
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>  
  </select>  

  <a href="#" id="add">add &gt;&gt;</a><br><br>

  <select multiple id="select2"></select>  
  <a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; remove</a>  

</body>  
</html>
```

I would like to replace the first multiple field with an input field.

How do I do that?

Comment: so what is the problem, what have you tried

Comment: In this case how do I get the value of an input field instead of multiple field in the function ready()

Comment: you can use `$('#inputfieldid').val()`

Comment: I think you need to use [`.detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of `.remove`

Comment: I tried:

    `$('#add').click(function() {  
        
        var value = $('#cellNbr').val(); 
    
        return !$('value').appendTo('#select2');          
    });`

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<html>  
<head>      
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

 <script type="text/javascript">  

$().ready(function() {  
    $('#add').click(function() {  
     var option = new Option($('#cellNbr').val(), "value"); 
     $('#select2').append(option);          
    });  

    $('#remove').click(function() {  
     $('#select2 option:selected').remove();  
    });  
   });     

 </script>  

</head>  

<body>  

    <input type="text" id="cellNbr">
  <a href="#" id="add">add &gt;&gt;</a><br><br>


  <select multiple id="select2"></select>  
  <a href="#" id="remove">&lt;&lt; remove</a>  


</body>  
</html>
```